# Java - Generic Static Abstract functionality

Tags: java, generics, static, abstract

```java
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class Example {
        public static abstract class item{
            public static abstract int getID(String s);//<<< the problem
            public abstract String doThingsWithID(int i);
        }

        public static class SpecificItem extends item{
            int positive;
            int negative;

            public SpecificItem(int p,int n){
                this.positive=p;
                this.negative=n;
            }

            protected enum IDHelper{
                POSITIVE(0),NEGATIVE(1);
                final int i;
                IDHelper(int i){this.i=i;}
            }

            public static int getID(String s){
                return IDHelper.valueOf(s).i;
            }

            public String doThingsWithID(int i){
                switch(i){
                    case 0:
                        return "positive="+String.valueOf(positive);
                    case 1:
                        return "negative="+String.valueOf(negative);
                    default:
                        return "shouldn't happen";
                }
            }
        }

        public class Container<T extends item>{
            public ArrayList<T> l;
            public int ID;

            public Container(ArrayList<T> l,String id){
                this.l=l;
                this.ID=T.getID(id);
            }

            public void doThings(){
                for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(l.get(i).doThingsWithID(ID)); 
                }
            }
        }
            public static void main(String[] args){
                ArrayList<SpecificItem> l = new ArrayList<>();
                l.add(new SpecificItem(1, -1));
                l.add(new SpecificItem(2, -2));
                Example main=new Example();
                Container<SpecificItem> cont=main.new Container<>(l, "POSITIVE");
                cont.doThings();
            }
    }
```

I have a code similar to this one. I want to be able to pass `String s` into a `Container` and forget about it, meaning give the `Container` constructor `String s` and have it do the `getID()` on its own. However, it appears I am forced to try to mimic the `getID()` functionality of `Container` constructor from outside, basically having a `Container(ArrayList<item> l, int id)` and expecting to pass in `SpecificItem.getID(String s)` to `id`, which I would ideally like to avoid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I primarily want the functionality of being able to link specific names to cases - basically the functionality of an enum - thus minimizing the amount of work if I want to rename a case.
And for anyone wondering, I am willing to modify most of the classes and methods, as long as I can retain the aforementioned functionality and can minimize the amount of "stuff" I need to pass into the function.
Also, I think the best option I have is to pass in a dummy `new SpecificItem()` that the `Container` constructor can use to do the `T.getID()`, and just have `getID` not be static. It feels kinda hacky though, so many there is a better option.

Comment: `pass String s into a Container and forget about it.` I don't know what this means.  Can you explain your actual use case more clearly?  And this also I don't know what you are trying to achieve: `I am forced to try to mimic the functionality of Container constructor`  Why?  It's your code, make the constructor do what you want.

Comment: @markspace Thank you for pointing out the `forget about it`, I have made an edit to make it clearer.
`Why? It's your code, make the constructor do what you want.` I am unsure what you mean by this because my question is specifically me pointing out that I am unable to do what I want.

Comment: Can you explain more on what you want your code to do? I'm guessing you want to call the functionality of the method `IDHelper` in your container class without the use of `SpecificItem`? Your container does not have access to the methods within your `SpecificItem` and cannot use them unless you passed a `SpecificItem` object instance into the container, in which case you can do `main.new Container<>(new SpecificItem(2, -2), "POSITIVE")` and modify your constructor and class fields to accept this if you only need one item.

Comment: Can you also please clarify, which classes (or their methods) you can, and are willing to modify, and which classes/methods signatures you want to keep unchanged.

Comment: Try calling `SpecificItem.IDHelper.valueOf(s).i` in lieu of  `T.getID(id)` you can account for `T` by moving your enum and `getID` methods to your abstract class if you know those will be consistent and calling `Item.IDHelper.valueOf(s).i`.

Comment: You could also send in the id instead of a string into the constructor of container so that you could call `getID` from the `item` subclass and pass that in. eg. `main.new Container<>(SpecificItem.getID())`.

Comment: @AliasCartellano yes, that is a solution, however I want to avoid doing this, because the `.getID()` functionality may be more complicated and there may be hidden logic in there that you aren't supposed to know about outside of the constructor.
So far my solution is a dummy `new SpecificItem()` I pass in to call the `getID()` on.